# Speech to text Ibm Watson C# with long audio more than 100 MB

Tags: c#, asp.net, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I am implementing C# code in which I am trying to transcribe audio more than of 100 mb but it is not allowing me to develop that required a program that can send more than 100 mb audio in C#
In this code I am using web socket but how I can send like streaming a audio

```
public static void CallWatson()
{
    using (var nf = new Notifier())
    using (var ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?watson-token=""))
    {
        string startActionjson = "{\"action\": \"start\", \"content-type\": \"audio/wav\", \"continuous\" : true, \"interim_results\": true}";
        ws.OnOpen += (sender, e) => ws.Send(startActionjson);

        // Set the WebSocket events.
        string result = string.Empty;

        ws.OnMessage += Ws_OnMessage;


        ws.OnError += (sender, e) =>
          nf.Notify(
            new NotificationMessage
            {
                Summary = "WebSocket Error",
                Body = e.Message,
                Icon = "notification-message-im"
            });

        ws.OnClose += (sender, e) =>
          nf.Notify(
            new NotificationMessage
            {
                Summary = String.Format("WebSocket Close ({0})", e.Code),
                Body = e.Reason,
                Icon = "notification-message-im"
            });

        ws.Connect();

        //ws.SendAsync(startActionjson, b =>
        //{
        //    if (b == true)
        //    {
        //        //send the audio as binary
        //        string filePath = "E:\\test33.wav";
        //        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        //        ws.SendAsync(bytes, b1 =>
        //        {
        //            if (b1)
        //                ws.Close();
        //        });

        //        // result+=result+ws.
        //    }
        //});
        // Connect to the server asynchronously.
        //ws.ConnectAsync ();

        //Console.WriteLine("\nType 'exit' to exit.\n");
        string filePath = "E:\\Test3.wav";
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            ws.SendAsync(bytes, b1 =>
            {
                if (b1)
                    ws.Close();
            });

        }

        //for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 1000000)
        //{
        //    Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //    byte[] buffer = new byte[1000000];
        //    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, i, buffer, 0, 128);
        //  //  ws.Send(buffer);
        //    ws.SendAsync(buffer, b1 =>
        //    {
        //        if (b1)
        //            ws.Close();
        //    });
        //}
    }
}

private static void Ws_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    string s = e.Data;
}
```

Comment: Please at least share your code.

Comment: What have you tried - please post the code!  What errors are you receiving specifically?

Comment: I atteched the code ... also help me to rectify the result properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation, there is a [100mb limit](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/input.shtml) regardless of input method. So you will have to split you audio files into chunks that are < 100mb.

To stream the audio, instead of calling `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);` and iterating over the result, I think you'll want to create a [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also, you shouldn't immediately close the websocket once you've reached the end of file - that may prevent you from receiving all of the results. Instead, send the string `{"action": "stop"}` and wait until you receive a response of `{"state": "listening"}` which [indicates that it has completed processing your audio](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/websockets.shtml#WSstop) and sent all text back.

**Update:** I got a hold of a windows machine, installed visual studio, and put together a working sample. I never did figure out what WebSocket API/Library you were using, but this just uses the built-in stuff that I could find documentation for on microsoft.com, so it should hopefully work for you.

I tested it with a couple of different .ogg and .wav files and confirmed that I get multiple interim and final results as expected.

```
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;


// Perform streaming transcription of an audio file using the IBM Watson Speech to Text service over a websocket
// http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/speech-to-text.html
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
namespace WatsonSTTWebsocketExample
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Transcribe();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        // http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/getting_started/gs-credentials.shtml
        static String username = "<username>";
        static String password = "<password>";

        static String file = @"c:\audio.wav";

        static Uri url = new Uri("wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize");
        static ArraySegment<byte> openingMessage = new ArraySegment<byte>( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            "{\"action\": \"start\", \"content-type\": \"audio/wav\", \"continuous\" : true, \"interim_results\": true}"
        ));
        static ArraySegment<byte> closingMessage = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            "{\"action\": \"stop\"}"
        ));


        static void Transcribe()
        {
            var ws = new ClientWebSocket();
            ws.Options.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
            ws.ConnectAsync(url, CancellationToken.None).Wait();

            // send opening message and wait for initial delimeter 
            Task.WaitAll(ws.SendAsync(openingMessage, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None), HandleResults(ws));

            // send all audio and then a closing message; simltaneously print all results until delimeter is recieved
            Task.WaitAll(SendAudio(ws), HandleResults(ws)); 

            // close down the websocket
            ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Close", CancellationToken.None).Wait();
        }

        static async Task SendAudio(ClientWebSocket ws)
        {

            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file))
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
                {
                    await ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(b), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                await ws.SendAsync(closingMessage, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }

        // prints results until the connection closes or a delimeterMessage is recieved
        static async Task HandleResults(ClientWebSocket ws)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (true)
            {
                var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);

                var result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None);

                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    return;
                }

                int count = result.Count;
                while (!result.EndOfMessage)
                {
                    if (count >= buffer.Length)
                    {
                        await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.InvalidPayloadData, "That's too long", CancellationToken.None);
                        return;
                    }

                    segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, count, buffer.Length - count);
                    result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None);
                    count += result.Count;
                }

                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, count);

                // you'll probably want to parse the JSON into a useful object here,
                // see ServiceState and IsDelimeter for a light-weight example of that.
                Console.WriteLine(message);

                if (IsDelimeter(message))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }


        // the watson service sends a {"state": "listening"} message at both the beginning and the *end* of the results
        // this checks for that
        [DataContract]
        internal class ServiceState
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string state = "";
        }
        static bool IsDelimeter(String json)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ServiceState));
            ServiceState obj = (ServiceState)ser.ReadObject(stream);
            return obj.state == "listening";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You could try compressing the audio with Flac or Opus to fit more audio into the 100mb limit ;)

Comment: How i can get the complete result because after sending all result it is closing the socket ... i am not able to identify that

Comment: Just don't call `ws.Close();` so quickly. Your code is closing the socket.

Comment: That i understand but ..then when or on which condition i will close the socket .. i am not getting any clue

Comment: At the end of the audio, you send the string `{"action": "stop"}`. Then you wait for the response `{"state": "listening"}` which indicates that Watson has finished processing your audio and sending results. Then you call `ws.Close();`

Comment: Note that you will get the message `{"state": "listening"}` twice - once before sending audio and once after. Obviously you don't want to close the websocket until the second one.

Comment: See I tried this     ws.SendAsync(bytes, b1 =>
                        {
                        if (b1)
                        {
                            ws.Send("{\"action\": \"stop\"}");
                        }
                        });                                                             but no result is coming from watson ...it is idle even i waited for 10 mins ...it is not even coming to next break point

Comment: So, it's been a while since I've done much c# (I'm usually on a mac) but looking at the docs (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.websocket.sendasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it looks like SendAsync returns a Task that you have to wait on and then send your stop message. I can't seem find any references to the callback version you're using, which might explain the trouble.  But I could be wrong. I'm downloading visual studio in a VM to try it out, but it looks like it's going to take a few hours...

Comment: I think the installer just hung; I let it run for like 8 hours and it's still in the same spot it was about 6 hours ago. I'll try and track down a real windows computer to try it out...

Comment: Thanks Nathan please provide any option if it possible ..thanks for trying I am also trying

Comment: I got it working, take a look at https://gist.github.com/nfriedly/0240e862901474a9447a600e5795d500 (I'll put a copy in the answer here too.)